# What happens when a package patches another, and then the original one is reloaded?

Tags: packages, documentclass-writing

I'm in the process of cleaning up my class file and I'm unclear as for the proper order of some lines. For example (replacing `\RequirePackage` with `\usepackage` and putting this in a MWE):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{amsmath}

\begin{document}
foo
\end{document}
```

Line 2, `mathtools` loads and patches `amsmath`. After that, line 4, according to its documentation, `tabularray` loads `amsmath` to provide additional features.

I guess that the modifications to `amsmath` provided by `mathtools` aren't overwritten by the latter, but I haven't found a way to confirm that there's no drawback to have some package try to load `amsmath` again.

The couple of packages used here are just an example, since I have similar concerns with packages that trigger loading of `tikz` or `hyperref`. So my question isn't (hopefully) about those specific examples. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Packages are never reloaded (terms and conditions may apply)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Packages are never reloaded (to the exception of `fontenc`, which is rather special).  The code in `\usepackage` ensures that a package is loaded only once, and any further attempt to load it again is either ignored, or raises an error.  That means any change you do to a package's macros are not overwritten.

If you just do `\usepackage` twice, the second call is just ignored.  If you call `\usepackage` with options to the package, and the options differ between one call and the next, an “Option clash” error is raised (there's a bit more to it, but essentially this is what happens).

Comment: Thank you. Just to be sure, is there a difference between `\usepackage` and `\RequirePackage` with regards to this?

Comment: @Miyase The only practical difference between them is that `\usepackage` cannot be used before `\documentclass`, while `\RequirePackage` can, otherwise they are identical.  `\usepackage` is the user interface, that should be used in a document, whereas `\RequirePackage` is the programmer interface, to be used in packages and classes, but it's more of a philosophical difference

Comment: OK, that I got that right at least. Now I can reorder my class file a bit with some peace of mind. Thans again.